# css doesn't work in macbook pro retina

Tags: css, macos

I use google chrome and mozilla firefox.

My menu bar in windows works perfectly.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2yPV.jpg

But in mac appears like this.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv5GB.jpg

This is my code:

```
    @media (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1920px) {

    .last-item .menu-title {
        margin-right: 3px;
    }

     #leo-mainnav ul li.last-item.active {
        background-color: #001b48;
        color: #fff;
        width: 134px;
    }

     #leo-mainnav ul li.last-item:hover {
        background-color: #001b48;
        color: #fff;
        width: 134px;
    }

}
```

Comment: are your browsers the same, check with safari on mac os x and on windows.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure in web browser 
for what you should you to make your formula work 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [normalise.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset your css in all browsers?